# Failing to Destroy a Cookie

Tags: apex, cookies

I have a class that gets the params from the URL, then if the system already have a cookie it retrieves their value.
if the system doesnt have a cookie it creates a cookie and assign a value.

Then just before the methods ends it check if the value is  a valid value, if it is not it should destroy the cookie. For some reason I am not able to achieve this last part.

the below code is an what i currently have:

```
public static string getcm() {
    string cmParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cm');
    Cookie cm = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('cm');
    string cmId;
    if(cm == null){
        if(cmParam != null){
            cm = new Cookie('cm',cmParam,null,31536000,false);
            ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{cm});  
            cmId = cm.getValue();
        }
    }else{
        cmId = cm.getValue();            
    }
    try{
        cmId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Client_ID__c =:cmId].Id ;
    } catch(QueryException qe){
        cmId = null;
        //delete the cookie as it has invalid data
        cm = new Cookie('cm',null,null,0,false);
    }
    return cmId;
}
```

I have also tried adding a question like

```
if (cmId == null){
    cm = new Cookie('cm',null,null,0,false);
}
```

but no success

Comment: Are you sure that your query `cmId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Client_ID__c =:cmId].Id` doesn't return any records, 100%? By specifying the 4th argument (maxAge) to `0` in your constructor the cookie should get deleted. Code looks fine, double check that your query fails and your catch block is executed.

Comment: Thanks Bachovski, I was missing setit up back again the cookie, ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{cm});  I have post my answer hopefuly it helps to anyone doing something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out what was going on. In the catch section I need it to setup again the cookie:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{cm});
```

so the actual code looks like:

```
public static string getcm() {
    string cmParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cm');
    Cookie cm = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('cm');
    string cmId;
    if(cm == null){
        if(cmParam != null){
            cm = new Cookie('cm',cmParam,null,31536000,false);
            ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{cm});  
            cmId = cm.getValue();
        }
    }else{
        cmId = cm.getValue();            
    }
    try{
        cmId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Client_ID__c =:cmId].Id ;
    } catch(QueryException qe){
        cmId = null;
        //delete the cookie as it has invalid data
        cm = new Cookie('cm',null,null,0,false);
        ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{cm}); 
    }
    return cmId;
}
```